# Custom FlexibleSpaceBar Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I want that  the title be under image and also be collaped with the image......

What I achieved

[image]

```
home: Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(

       expandedHeight: 220.0,
        floating: true,
        pinned: true,
        snap: true,
        elevation: 50,
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('Title',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                )),
            background: Image.network(
              'https://images.pexels.com/photos/443356/pexels-photo-443356.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )
        ),
      ),
      new SliverList(
          delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(_buildList(50))
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

what I want

[image]

Thanks for help

Answer (score 8):

I hope I'm not too late, and my answer will be helpful for you.

[image]

If you check the `flexibleSpace` parameter type, you notice that it takes any `Widget`.

So you can create your own widget, and move title from `SliverAppBar` to your `NewFlexibleSpaceWidget`.

Plus you can go and check [FlexibleSpaceBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html), to see how flutter dev team implement it.

When we shrinking or expending the `SliverAppBarWidget`, it changes `BoxConstraints` of the `FlexibleSpace` so it means that we can catch new height by using `LayoutBuilder` which will give us current `BoxConstraints`. And we can use them to draw animations.

[image]

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: controller,
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 220.0,
          floating: true,
          pinned: true,
          snap: true,
          elevation: 50,
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.filter_1),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          flexibleSpace: _MyAppSpace(),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            List.generate(
              200,
              (index) => Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text('text $index'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _MyAppSpace extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyAppSpace({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, c) {
        final settings = context
            .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<FlexibleSpaceBarSettings>();
        final deltaExtent = settings.maxExtent - settings.minExtent;
        final t =
            (1.0 - (settings.currentExtent - settings.minExtent) / deltaExtent)
                .clamp(0.0, 1.0) as double;
        final fadeStart = math.max(0.0, 1.0 - kToolbarHeight / deltaExtent);
        const fadeEnd = 1.0;
        final opacity = 1.0 - Interval(fadeStart, fadeEnd).transform(t);

        return Opacity(
          opacity: opacity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/443356/pexels-photo-443356.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Title',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 26.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```